# Why I cannot select today orders return no rows found?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select today orders only but its return no rows found
but there is a lot of orders for today

I am using oracle SQL

I tried this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM LAB_RESULTS
WHERE LAB_RESULTS.SERV_REQUEST_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

I tried also this query but same no rows returned :

```
SELECT * 
FROM LAB_RESULTS
WHERE LAB_RESULTS.SERV_REQUEST_DATE >=  TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND LAB_RESULTS.SERV_REQUEST_DATE <   TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

the output always:

> no rows Returned

why its not return today orders is there need to search by time from 00:00 till 23:59 ?

I solved it by adding date and time in the QUERY

```
SELECT * 
FROM LAB_RESULTS
WHERE LAB_RESULTS.SERV_REQUEST_DATE 
BETWEEN  TO_DATE('23/08/2023 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')   
AND TO_DATE('23/08/2023 23:59:55', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: In Oracle, a `DATE` always has a time component (even if the client application you are using chooses not to show it) so to get results for a day you need to query a range covering that 24-hour period; so `WHERE serv_request_date >= DATE '2023-08-23' AND serv_request_date < DATE '2023-08-24'`. You are only looking for rows at midnight on that day and not at any other time of day.

Comment: Yes, `DATE` in Oracle is a misnomer; it is a datetime really. So, maybe you just made the same mistake. Is `SERV_REQUEST_DATE` supposed to hold dates as its name suggests? Or does it hold datetimes instead? The query will be fine, if `SERV_REQUEST_DATE` only contains dates (datetimes with the time set to midnight). You can run `select * from lab_results where serv_request_date <> trunc(serv_request_date)` to see if you are mistakenly storing times in your date column. You can guarantee time-free dates with a check constraint.

Comment: @MT0 yes I solved it by adding the date and time because the column save date and time in the database

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're selecting rows whose `serv_request_date` is **equal** to `23.08.2023 00:00:00` (and there are no such rows).

Try

```
where serv_request_date >= date '2023-08-23'
  and serv_request_date <  date '2023-08-24'
```

instead.

---

Another option, which is simpler to write, is

```
where trunc(serv_request_date) = date '2023-08-23'
```

but it wouldn't use index on `serv_request_date` column (if it exists), so performance might suffer **unless** you (have) create(d) a function-based index.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving no response because there are no rows to return from the query. I'd usually count the rows first to see if there is anything to do, then if the row count is greater than 0 run the query. Something like this

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 'No Rows Returned'  ELSE 'data present' END as testresult FROM LAB_RESULTS WHERE LAB_RESULTS.SERV_REQUEST_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

If this is part of a stored procedure (or in code) you can then use the result to run the main query

```
IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LAB_RESULTS WHERE LAB_RESULTS.SERV_REQUEST_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') > 0 THEN SELECT * FROM LAB_RESULTS WHERE LAB_RESULTS.SERV_REQUEST_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')  AND TO_DATE('23/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: Question is related to **Oracle**, and such a code wouldn't work there. IF belongs to PL/SQL which requires an INTO clause for SELECT statements. Besides, you can't use `IF SELECT ...` - first you have to *select* and then use its outcome in IF. Therefore, from my point of view, that part of your answer is useless in this context.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot I appreciate the feedback. Oracle isn't my wheelhouse but just wanted to give a conceptual framework to move forward from. I see you have an answer above so potentially you could rewrite my answer in PL/SQL in such a way that would be usable :)

Comment: I guess Ziad will read your answer and and use idea you presented if he uses a stored procedure (and adjust that code if needed). As there's no such evidence (that procedure is being involved), I won't modify what I wrote so far, but - thanks for the offer!